# Calculate a point between 2 colors

Tags: python, rgb

I am looking to make a function that can output colors of a gradient. Let me explain more...

```python
iterations = 5
startcolor = 0xa480ff
endcolor = 0x80bdff
colors = []

for x in range(1, iterations):
    colors[x-1] = color
```

In the `colors[x-1] = color` line, I would like to calculate the color that would be at the percentage of `x` on a gradient. For example, if `x` is `3` and `iterations` is `5`, then `color` would be halfway between a gradient of `startcolor` and `endcolor`. `1` would be `startcolor`, and `5` would be `endcolor`.

Comment: "colors of a gradient" isn't meaningful on its own. You need a [colormap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_gradient). Do you want to interpolate in RGB space? In L\*a\*b\* space? Something else? You've got to choose a space to perform your gradient in.

Comment: @silvio-mayolo Are you saying that there is no way to work this out without first generating an image of the gradients? "Do you want to interpolate in RGB space? In L*a*b* space? Something else? You've got to choose a space to perform your gradient in." Could you please further explain this, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Human eye are more sensitive to some colours than others, so although a simple linear interpolation for R, G, and B channels might be acceptable, it's not the only (or the best) way to create gradients. @SilvioMayolo is trying to clarify that.

Comment: @Selcuk I appreciate this, however I think that in this case a simple linear interpolation should be acceptable. Do you know how I would go about doing this, or any articles relating to this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with generating images. Color is a complicated thing (like [really complicated](https://xkcd.com/1882/)), so you need to choose a representation of color as a vector in order to do interpolation. Going from red to green in RGB space is going to look entirely different than going from red to green (the same two colors) in the L\*a\*b\* space I mentioned. If you just want to go RGB, then you've got two 3D vectors, so interpolate them componentwise (it looks like you've got a hex number, so you'll need to convert it to a vector first).

Answer (score 1):

If you think that a simple linear interpolation is sufficient as you stated in your comment, you may give this a try:

```python
iterations = 5
startcolor = 0xa480ff
endcolor = 0x80bdff
colors = []

start_r, start_g, start_b = startcolor >> 16, startcolor >> 8 & 0xff, startcolor & 0xff
end_r, end_g, end_b = endcolor >> 16, endcolor >> 8 & 0xff, endcolor & 0xff
delta_r, delta_g, delta_b = (end_r - start_r) / iterations, (end_g - start_g) / iterations, (
            end_b - start_b) / iterations

for x in range(iterations + 1):
    r = int(start_r + delta_r * x)
    g = int(start_g + delta_g * x)
    b = int(start_b + delta_b * x)
    colors.append(int(r << 16 | g << 8 | b))

print(*(f"{c:x}" for c in colors))
```

This should print:

```
a480ff 9c8cff 9598ff 8ea4ff 87b0ff 80bdff
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code I made trying to do something similar. It good to note in my case I want a string.

As you can see I am lerping between each color value rgb(not a) individualy and adding them back together

I made this pretty quickly and haven't tested anything but the two functions.

```
def lerp(a, b, p):
    return a + ((b - a) * p)

def lerpH(c1, c1, p):
    r = lerp(int(c1[:2], 16), int(c2[:2], 16), p)
    g = lerp(int(c1[2:4], 16), int(c2[2:4], 16), p)
    b = lerp(int(c1[4:6], 16), int(c2[4:6] ,16), p)
    t = lambda _x: str(hex(int(_x)))[2:]
    return f'{t(r)}{t(g)}{t(b)}'

iterations = 5
startcolor = "a480ff" 
# startcolor = str(hex(0xa480ff))[2:]  # for hex()
endcolor = "80bdff"
# endcolor = str(hex(0x80bdff))[2:]  # for hex()
colors = []

for x in range(0, iterations):
    colors[x] = lerpH(startcolor, endcolor, float(x)/iterations)
    #colors[x] = int(colors[x], 16)  # this is to convert back to hex
```

Comment: The colors in OP's code are integers not hexstrings.